# how to make footer width responsible in wordpress (theme twenty thirteen)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, themes

I have a problem with the site: http://elsiea.md/ .
When i size the window of web browser to 997px or less, appears horizontal scroll.
I thnik the problem is in this div tag:

How can I change it's style to make responsive site work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is a min-width defined  here.

.archive-header, .search .page-header, .archive .page-header, .blog .page-header, .error404 .page-content, .search .page-content, .archive .page-content, .attachment .entry-header, .attachment .entry-content, .post-navigation .nav-links, .sidebar .site-info, .site-footer .widget-area{
      min-width: 980px; 
    }

You can overwrite it when screen size is smaller than 980px.